# Is it possible to create tables from an sql dump file using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pg-dump

I have a database that contains one table (say stores). I reflected this database in my models and work with it from there. In my code, I only read from this table. I created some other tables in the models file using sqlalchemy declarative_base. It works well as expected. In my automated tests, I want to replicate this database and work with it. The difference is that I also write to the 'stores' table in my test to create mock values. I then drop the database at the end of the test run. I want to be able to recreate the table at the start of the test. Using metadata.create_all() will only create tables in the declarative_base. Since the table is reflected and I have the database dump file that creates the table, how can I create the 'store' table in the database in my test setup file. I tried creating a sqlalchemy connection and passing the sql generated from the dump file into the execute method like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("postgres_url")
con = engine.connect()
file = open('\path\to\generated\sqldump\file')
file.seek(0)
sql = file.read()
rsql = sql.replace("\n", " ")

con.execute(sql)
con.execute(rsql)
```

I know I could create the database and run the sqldump from psql at initial database setup and only truncate the tables after each test run. I thought it would be nice to drop the tables and recreate them afresh so I tried the above and go an error.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html): "To restore from such a script [dump file], feed it to psql."

Comment: That would be run in the terminal. I want to be able to run it programatically when I call the setup fixture.

Comment: You can use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).